# Selecting values from an arry and storing in a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, rhino

I am trying to return the second and third value in an array - but struggling to do so with my limited JS knowledge.

I have two arrays which are combined into one and looks like this:

```
"0.003839795 - clothes ,0.171756425 - food",0.00741361072561247 - electronics"
```

I want to order the array by highest score, and then pull back the score and the category into separate variables.

```
category1 = value
category1score = value
cat2 score = value
cat2 score = value
```

The script below works and can return the top product name, but I can't work out how to make it return the associated score or the second and third prod/scores in the array...

```
var product;
var finalString=","+user.get('array1')+user.get('array2');
var finalArray = finalString.split(',');
product = finalArray.sort()[finalArray.length - 1] +' - ';
return product.split(' - ')[1];
```

The output for above array would look like:

```
cat1 = food 
cat1score = 0.171756425 
cat2 = electronics 
cat2score = 0.00741361072561247 
cat3= clothes 
cat3score = 0.003839795
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output of the sample input array that you provided?

Comment: Hi - I've updated the post with expected output above. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses a temporary `array of objects`, and sorts by a field in the object.  The parsing provides some flexibility for `optional spaces`.  It also converts the score to a float to ensure leading zeros, negative signs, etc, do not cause inaccurate ordering.

```js
const data = `0.003839795 - clothes ,0.171756425 - food ,0.00741361072561247 - electronics`

let items = [];

const parts = data.split(/\s*,\s*/)
parts.forEach(function (part) {
  const pair = part.split(/\s*-\s*/);
  items.push({
    score: parseFloat(pair[0]),
    name: pair[1]
  });
})

// sort by score, descending
items.sort(function (a, b) { return b.score - a.score });

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log('cat' + (i+1) + '= ' + items[i].name);
  console.log('cat' + (i+1) + 'score= '+ items[i].score);
}
```

Here is your updated snippet.  You need to sort and then reverse.  And change the order of some of your logic.

```js
var product;
var finalString = `,,,0.003839795 - clothes ,0.171756425 - food ,0.00741361072561247 - electronics`

var finalArray = finalString.split(',');
finalArray.sort().reverse()
finalArray = finalArray.filter(function(it) {
  return it.trim().length > 0
})

var rets=[];
for (var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
  var product = finalArray[i]
  var pair = product.split(' - ');

  var ret = {
    product: pair[1],
    score: pair[0]
  }
  rets.push(ret)
  console.log(ret)
}
```

Comment: @StevenSpungin - Solution worked - thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing that you can do:
consider this is your array:

```
let arr = ["0.003839795 - clothes" ,"0.171756425 - food","0.00741361072561247 - electronics"];
```

You can split each item of the array into two individual arrays per item.
So basically:

`"0.003839795 - clothes"` becomes `["0.003839795","clothes"]`

This code snippet will do that:

```
let splittedArray = arr.map((value) => {
    return value.split('-').map((v) => v.trim());
});
```

Now you can just sort them with this logic:

```
splittedArray.sort((x, y) => y[0] - x[0]);
```

Now, the array is sorted in ascending order and looks something like this:

```
[
  [
    "0.171756425",
    "food"
  ],
  [
    "0.00741361072561247",
    "electronics"
  ],
  [
    "0.003839795",
    "clothes"
  ]
]
```

Now, you can just take out values out of this sorted array simply this way:

```
cat1 = splittedArray[0][1]; 
cat1score = splittedArray[0][0];
cat2 = splittedArray[1][1]; 
cat2score = splittedArray[1][0];
cat3= splittedArray[2][1];
cat3score = splittedArray[0][0];
```

You can also write these in a simple for loop and get this task done^

Comment: Thans for this Sivan. I should have stated that tool uses Rhino JS, and it looks like your code doesn't work with that version. Is there a way to modify the script that does work in my original post, to look for 2nd, 3rd products? I don't mind if I have to run three separate scripts to get the output... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you begin with this input:

```
const arr = [
  '0.003839795 - clothes',
  '0.171756425 - food',
  '0.00741361072561247 - electronics'
  // ...
];
```

From there, you want to first sort the array in descending order (highest to lowest), then transform (map) the output into the below output order:

```
cat1 = food 
cat1score = 0.171756425 
cat2 = electronics 
cat2score = 0.00741361072561247 
cat3 = clothes 
cat3score = 0.003839795
```

You can map => sort => reverse => format values using composable functions:

```
const arr = [
  '0.003839795 - clothes',
  '0.171756425 - food',
  '0.00741361072561247 - electronics'
  // ...
];

const toTuples = val => val.split(' - ');
const floatSort = (a, b) => parseFloat(a[0]) - parseFloat(b[0]);

const toOutputFormat = (tuple, index) => `
cat${index + 1} = ${tuple[1]}
cat${index + 1}score = ${tuple[0]}
`

arr.map(toTuples).sort(floatSort).reverse().map(toOutputFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// initializing categories
categories = ["Food", "Electronics", "Cloths"];
// initializing scores
scores = [0.171, 0.0074, 0.0038];
// constructing array or array with categories and scores
out = [];
categories.forEach(function(d, i){
 out.push([d, scores[i]]); 
});
// sorting out array based on the score
out.sort(function(x, y) {
 return y[1]-x[1];
});
```

Here is the code for you.
I have used to arrays then merged it into one ans then sorted the merged array on the basis of score.